# Why are namespaces acting up in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, namespaces

I've just converted a project to VS 2010 and something really weird is going on with namespaces.
Let me give an example, the following code used to work in VS2008:

```
namespace MySystem.Core.Object
{
    using MySystem.Core.OtherObject;
    ...
}
```

But now it doesn't, it either wants the whole thing to be put outside of the namespace like this:

```
using MySystem.Core.OtherObject;

namespace MySystem.Core.Object
{
    ...
}
```

or be rewritten it like:

```
namespace MySystem.Core.Object
{
    using OtherObject;
    ...
}
```

I understand why this works and maybe is the correct way of handling this, but now we'd have to change thousands of lines of code! Which is not cool.

Any idea to circumvent this requirement?

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing `using` directives with namespaces?

Comment: oops, yeah I had too many usings in there. it was a long day!

Comment: You know, I just tried it myself, and it works very well. Do you happen to have a beta of some sort? What's the version of VS?

Comment: I have the RTM version of 2010 professional installed actually

Comment: Are you missing the `namespace` keyword? None of the code snippets you've got there would compile...

Comment: Corrected the missing namespace keywords.

Comment: Please give an example of a minimal repro case with the specific error you are seeing.  The ability to use a namespace within namespace scope works fine in VS2010.  You can prove this to yourself by writing a simple Hello World app that prints to the console and move the "using System" within your namespace.

Comment: I never been able to reproduce this, aside from a specific solution file I was working with. But I've long lost access to that solution.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you converted to C# from VB.NET.  "Usings" in VB.NET are the same thing as "Imports" in C#.  So when the conversion/upgrade took place, it figured you meant to use a using(){} statement and placed that inside the namespace.  Rewrite your includes as "imports" and it should work.